# Install specific version of Git in Docker image

Tags: apt, docker

I'd like to fix Git version used in my image to the `2.9.3`.

However, when I run

```
RUN apt-get install git=2.9.3 -y
```

it doesn't work:

```
Version '2.9.3' for 'git' was not found
```

How to correctly specify Git version?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a package version, not the upstream software version:

```
apt-get install git=1:2.9.3-1
```

You also need to make sure the package repositories you're using actually contain the version you're after. If you're using Debian for your base images, you can find the appropriate [snapshot](http://snapshot.debian.org/) repository:

```
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20160817T042105Z/ sid main
```

(based on the available snapshots of [git 2.9.3-1](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/git/1%3A2.9.3-1/)).

Comment: Doesn't work: `sudo apt-get install git=2.9.3-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.9.3-1' for 'git' was not found`

Comment: @Stephen How do we know the package version? For e.g. what's the package version for the latest 2.34.1?

Comment: @Koder101 look at [the available snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/git/); the 2.34.1 package is version 1:2.34.1-1.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks. Since I am installing it under ubuntu-20.04 docker image, so the debian snapshot isn't valid there. When I did `apt-cache madison git` it gave me `1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.2` which works fine. However, I wonder do we have the package snapshot for docker ubuntu images too?

Comment: @Koder101 if `apt install git` gives you a package that works fine for your purposes, you should use that. I’m not aware of a snapshot repository for Ubuntu.

Comment: @StephenKitt I had initially used `apt install git`, however, due to compliance I have to follow [hadonlint](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/wiki/DL3018) which throws a warning to specify the version.

Comment: @Koder101 that’s an anti-pattern with Ubuntu-based images, because of the way the repositories are maintained: fixing the version with `apt install` will ensure you *don’t* get security updates for the packages whose versions are fixed.